# How to properly integrate Orbeon with Grails?

Tags: grails, orbeon

Attempting to integrate Orbeon 3.9 CE with Grails 1.3.7, using the recommended separate war deployment approach specified here:
http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xforms-with-java-applications

After having created the form and viewed in Orbeon Form Builder, I placed the resulting xml in a views/xforms directory under the root of the Grails app and called the file `test.gsp`. I also placed the image file for the logo of the form in the same directory.  I created a war file and placed in an instance of Tomcat 7 where the `orbeon.war` was deployed.  When I invoke the `test.gsp`, the form comes up sans the image file or any of the labels specified in the XForm!

1. Why would all labels not render?
2. Where do I place resources such as an image file so that it appears?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you don't go the route of using Form Builder to generate a form, and copying the source somewhere else. It see 3 main drawbacks:

1. Some elements generated by Form Builder are expected to be interpreted by the Form Builder runtime; so they won't be understood by Orbeon Forms when they are generated by your code. I am thinking of `fr:view`, `fr:section` and the like.
2. Form Runner services used for persistence, internationalization, PDF generation… most likely won't work.
3. The copy-paste process is by itself not recommendable.

The separate deployment assumes that you're using another framework and that you're going to be writing XForms in a text editor, while Form Builder is targeted at "form authors" (not necessarily developers); it uses its own runtime which requires request to hit Orbeon Forms, that is those URLs starting with `/fr`.

Comment: Thanks for your insights! But we really are looking to allow non-developers to develop the forms. Is there a workflow that could be used to achieve this?

Comment: You could take the code generated by Form Builder, and write a JSP taglib that interprets the fr:* tags, and replaces them by HTML, before the output is sent to Orbeon Forms. That seems feasible, but is a project on its own. You could also leave the form exist in the Orbeon web app, and use an iframe, or server-side include to include it in your page. The former is simple but has the downsides of iframes; the latter is more complicated, as you need to make sure that resources (images, CSS, JS) are served properly, and that Ajax request are forwarded properly to the Orbeon web app.

Comment: I should add that if you're using a nightly build from May 25, 2011 or later, then your separate app can generate Form Runner elements, and they will be correctly interpreted by Form Runner. So with nightly builds, you might be one step closer to what you are trying to do. In other words, nightly builds should take care of point 1 above.

Answer (score 0):

All static files, like images must be placed at `web-app/*/` dir, and linked by using `<g:resource>` tag.

For example, for images you have to put your image ('test.png' for example) into `web-app/images/` and use following code in your gsp: `<img src="${resource(dir:'/images/settings', file:'test.png')}">`

See docs for this tag: http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/resource.html